# Laravel Call to undefined method in eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to store a simple form into my database. My model is that I have jobs which where each job can contain several task. Therefore my Models look like this:

##### User

```
public function jobs()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Job::class);
}
```

##### Job

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}
```

##### Task

```
public function job()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Job::class);
}
```

When I now would like to store in the TaskController.php with the following code:

```
    public function store(Request $request, Job $job)
    {
        $request['job_id'] = $job->id;
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'message' => 'required|string|max:255',
        ]);
 
        $request->user()->jobs()->tasks()->create($validated);
 
        return redirect(route('tasks.index'));
    }
```

I get the error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::tasks()

I am pretty sure I am doing a rookie mistake passing the $request but can not figure it out. Thank you for any help!

Comment: `jobs()` returns a Relationship to multiple `Job` rows, not a single instance, so you can't chain it to `tasks()`. `jobs()->first()->tasks()` would work to create a `Task` for the first `Job` associated to the `User`, or `->jobs()->find($id)->tasks()`, where `$id` is the ID of a `Job` associated to the `User`.

Comment: Simply: for which job belong the tasks that you are trying to create ?

Comment: Appreciate all your efforts! I have put more code from the (original, wrong) TaskController.php to make the question more clear. I would like to assign the task to a specific job $id as stated by Tim Lewis. So I stated:

Comment: With your update, you can do `$job->tasks()->create($validated)`, or `$request->user()->jobs()->find($job->id)->tasks()->create($validated)`, but that is kinda redundant as `$request->user()->jobs()->find($job->id)` would return the same thing as `$job` already is defined as.

Comment: Appreciate all your efforts! I So I stated: `$request->user()->jobs()->find($request['job_id'])->tasks()->create($validated); ` which now works but seems not to pass the the user_id in the SQL statement which is a field in tasks table. Any idea why not? Would I need to define a relation between User and Task model as well?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you are calling `tasks` on `jobs`, but `jobs()` is a relationship, not a model nor a collection.

To fix it, you have to go over each one:

```php
$request->user()
    ->jobs()
    ->each(function (Job $job) use ($validated) {
        $job->tasks()
            ->create($validated);
    });
```

Or, you could try to use a [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

Comment: This is correct, so long as the expectation is to create the same `Task` for every `Job` associated with the `User` 

Comment: Correct! I am still a little bit confused, so my answer may not be 100% right, but I think this is what the user wants

Comment: Haha same, it was unclear if the Task was supposed to be created for a single Job, or all of them, or some other arbitrary thing. My comment handles single, your answer covers multiple, so all-in-all, they should have what they need. Cheers! 

Answer (score 0):

Calling the relationship function (`$request->user()->jobs()`) will get you the relationship class (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany`), not the collection itself. Accessing like `$request->user()->jobs` will get you the jobs collection.

Comment: While this is correct, changing the code to `$request->user()->jobs->tasks()->create($validated);` will still fail, with a different error: *"Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::tasks does not exist"*. You'd still need to do `jobs->first()` (or `first(function (...))`) to tell the code **which `Job` to create the `Task` for**. That's the issue here, not the usage of `jobs()` vs `jobs`.